# How to verify a text-box is disabled when the element has no read-only and enabled attributes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to verify a text-box is disabled when the element has no read-only and enabled attributes using selenium webdriver and java?

"

"

I tried "isenabled" and "getattribute(readonly)" - but both do not work in my case

Comment: <div ng-bind-html="model.submission.submission_text" class="textbox ng-binding"><p>test</p></div>

Comment: Please, be more specific. What do you get using `isEnabled()`

Comment: If the given things are not able to give u desired solution, then u can use one small work around. Type Something in the given Edit box and then Check the text which u have typed. If the text is there it means the box is enabled else its disabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement some_element = driver.findElement(By.id("some_id"));
String readonly = some_element.getAttribute("readonly");
Assert.assertNotNull(readonly);
```

Do NOT verify getAttribute("readonly").equals("true") or similar, in different browsers it can be different as well. (readonly="readonly" in IE, readonly="" in FF, etc.)

Comment: if you try with isEnabled() , u should get false as return , then the element is disabled.

Comment: You will get error `AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'isEnabled'`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround you can try element.sendKeys('foo') and catch the InvalidElementStateException (pythonic, don't know about Java).